# websites or software for creating a 3D character

Tags: 3d-view, blend4web

Could you please guys give me some good websites or software for creating a 3D character so I can use my own character in Blender? it is kind of hard to create a character in Blender.

Comment: Sorry but this question doesn't seem to be about using Blender and any answers would in any case be opinion-based so it's likely to be closed. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. You could try asking on [Blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org/).

Comment: *MakeHuman* is listed in the linked *Resources for Blender* page under *"External Tools"*. There is also another free add-on called [MB-Lab](https://mb-lab-community.github.io/MB-Lab.github.io/).